# Reputation above 10, but cannot answer a protected question

Tags: support, bug

For some reason, I could not provide an answer to the following question:

[Can't pay with PayPal balance, only shows credit card to pay with](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/47874/cant-pay-with-paypal-balance-only-shows-credit-card-to-pay-with)

[image: screenshot showing that I have rep but no answer button.]

---

[image: entire page longshot]

But my reputation is actually well above 10.    No answer question button.  So what did I do wrong?

Comment: The question is now unprotected.

Answer (score 3):

"Association bonus does not count" 
Sorry, you have a +1 rep at Money.SE for this purpose.

Comment: Hmmm.  I read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus-and-how-does-it-work) which seemed to clarify this.  I think it is a little silly, but whatever.   I was actually trying to post my experience as an answer to the q.  I thought I was already trusted enough to do this.

Comment: And also see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129223/325059) about the "recent" change to exclude the association bonus.